# Wrong datPicker format in editText

Tags: java, android, datepicker

I have a datePicker that I want to display in the editText when I take the date from it, it has the wrong format.
For example, I
Jan / 01/2020
I choose.
But inside text editing
It shows 2020/0/1 instead of 2020/01/01

open datePicker:

```
new SpinnerDatePickerDialogBuilder()
                       .context(AddProjectActivity.this)
                       .callback(AddProjectActivity.this)
                       .spinnerTheme(R.style.NumberPickerStyle)
                       .showTitle(true)
                       .showDaySpinner(true)
                       .defaultDate(2017, 0, 1)
                       .maxDate(2100, 0, 1)
                       .minDate(2020, 0, 1)
                       .build()
                       .show();
```

```
 @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        meEdtDate.setText(year + "/" + monthOfYear + "/" + dayOfMonth);
        date = getDate(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
    }

    private Date getDate(int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);

        return calendar.getTime();
    }
```

set date to editText:

```
 SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
            String dateStr = simpleDateFormat.format(projectEntity.getDate());
            meEdtDate.setText(dateStr);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using classes from the current package, java.time, for date handling.

You can create a LocalDate from year, month and day like this

```
private static LocalDate getDate(int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    return LocalDate.of(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
}
```

And then format it into a String like this

```
LocalDate date = getDate(2020, 1, 1);
String dateString = date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd"));
```

Comment: Please don't post comments like that, they are completely pointless. If there is an error then say _what_ the error is.

Comment: could you please edit my codes with your codes that you suggested.

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/time/LocalDate;

Comment: Did you add an import of java.time.*?

Comment: import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

Comment: Then I don't understand how you can get that error.